# How do I stop these nodes from running

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For context, I am working on a simulation for a robot and I am using an external library for pointcloud to laserscan conversion. Everything was originally working fine, but all of a sudden I have these ros2 nodes running which I can't figure out how to kill. I believe they are stopping my TF frames from registering. I have tried using the kill command and trying to find them using "htop", and I have tried finding them in my system monitor, but I can't seem to locate them anywhere to try and shut them down. These are the names of the nodes and the properties:

```
/vtr/boreas_odometry_feaeexyoeg
/vtr/boreas_odometry_xkzleovjry
/vtr/boreas_odometry_yvjvpzmakr
```

from node info:

```
/vtr/boreas_odometry_feaeexyoeg
  Subscribers:
    /clock: rosgraph_msgs/msg/Clock
    /parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent
  Publishers:
    /clock: rosgraph_msgs/msg/Clock
    /parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent
    /rosout: rcl_interfaces/msg/Log
    /tf: tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage
    /tf_static: tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage
    /vtr/boreas_2021_09_09_15_28_lidar_odometry: std_msgs/msg/String
    /vtr/filtered_point_cloud: sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2
    /vtr/loc_path: nav_msgs/msg/Path
    /vtr/odometry: nav_msgs/msg/Odometry
    /vtr/raw_point_cloud: sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2
    /vtr/submap_odo: sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2
    /vtr/udist_point_cloud: sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2
  Service Servers:
    /vtr/boreas_odometry_feaeexyoeg/describe_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/DescribeParameters
    /vtr/boreas_odometry_feaeexyoeg/get_parameter_types: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameterTypes
    /vtr/boreas_odometry_feaeexyoeg/get_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameters
    /vtr/boreas_odometry_feaeexyoeg/list_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/ListParameters
    /vtr/boreas_odometry_feaeexyoeg/set_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters
    /vtr/boreas_odometry_feaeexyoeg/set_parameters_atomically: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParametersAtomically
  Service Clients:
    /vtr/boreas_odometry_feaeexyoeg/describe_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/DescribeParameters
    /vtr/boreas_odometry_feaeexyoeg/get_parameter_types: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameterTypes
    /vtr/boreas_odometry_feaeexyoeg/get_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameters
    /vtr/boreas_odometry_feaeexyoeg/list_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/ListParameters
    /vtr/boreas_odometry_feaeexyoeg/set_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters
    /vtr/boreas_odometry_feaeexyoeg/set_parameters_atomically: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParametersAtomically
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416225/how-do-i-stop-these-nodes-from-running/) by [koener](https://answers.ros.org/users/152794/koener/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2023-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-06-06**:
Where ROS 1 was `localhost` by default, ROS 2 is `everything-on-your-network` by default.

Is someone else perhaps also running ROS 2 nodes on your network?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-06-07**:
If @gvdhoorn's guess is correct, you need to set a unique `domain id`. This is a DDS config parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for the responses. It wasn't any of these issues but I appreciate them being addressed. I am new to ROS2 and LINUX so I may have been missing something when trying to find these nodes in system manager, but what fixed it was forcing ROS2 to crash by shutting down python in terminal.

---

Originally posted by [koener](https://answers.ros.org/users/152794/koener/) with karma: 16 on 2023-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0